# How do I numerically position a barcode in reportlab?

Tags: python, reportlab

I have a bit of a specific case that I can't seem to figure out a solution to. I'm writing a shipping label template object in ReportLab for Python. I have the following code that creates a barcode as a drawing.

```
uspsBarcode = createBarcodeDrawing('USPS_4State', value=self.imbval, routing=self.zip4.replace('-',''))
print uspsBarcode.getBounds() # print out of position and scale
```

Using that code, I later add it to a shape group, and that shape group gets returned. So I need the barcode to be positioned relative to the object. I can't seem to find any way to pass positioning to this, even though I've dug through the inheritance. Though as you can see from the print, positioning is set *somwhere*.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone else that runs across this issue. It turns out that if you put the barcode drawing in a shape group, the shape group container can be moved around numerically with the shift function.

```
uspsBarcode = shapes.Group()
bc = createBarcodeDrawing('USPS_4State', value=self.imbVal, routing=self.zip4.replace('-',''))
uspsBarcode.add(bc)
uspsBarcode.shift(self.x+(s*0.2), self.y)
```